# Not able to avoid padding problems even after setting fitsSystemWindows to true in andorid

Tags: android

The code is below. Now fitsSystemWindows works fine for the app bar but the frame layout in the below code which display the main content, gets the first element underneath the app bar even after using fitsSystemWindows and setting it to true for the frame Layout. Please help me understand why is it not working.

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<!-- CoordinatorLayout is used to create scrolling and "floating" effects within a layout -->
<!-- This is typically the root layout which wraps the app bar and content -->
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout


    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- AppBarLayout is a wrapper for a Toolbar in order to apply scrolling effects. -->
    <!-- Note that AppBarLayout expects to be the first child nested within a CoordinatorLayout -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:popupTheme="@style/StyleForMyOverflowMenu">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="News"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add "appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to FrameLayout and problem solved

```
<!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works. But i would like to understand why it didn't work before and why is it working now. Can you please also try to help me understand that.?